# Apache spark taking average by key with python

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, pyspark

My solution is like below code but it's with scala.

Is there any person to convert it to python for taking average by key ?

```
val avgValue = data.mapValues((_, 1)
        .reduceByKey((x, y) => (x._1 + y._1, x._2 + y._2))
        .mapValues{ case (sum, count) => (1.0 * sum) / count }
        .collectAsMap()
```

My sample dataset:

```
customerid|location||deviceid|year|  |result|

|         7|       6|    dev14|2016   22.0|
|         7|       6|    dev11|2016   21.0|
|         2|       6|    dev12|2016   62.0|
|         2|       6|    dev18|2016   28.0|
|         1|       6|    dev15|2016   22.0|
```

And i want to take each -customerid's avarage -results.

Comment: can you share some sample data ?

Comment: customerid|location||deviceid|year|  |result|

|         7|       6|    dev14|2016  25.0|
|         7|       6|    dev11|2016   25.0|

Comment: i want to take each customerid's result avarages

Comment: please edit your question to add information and format it. This is not readable

Comment: okey have already editted

Comment: What have you tried so far? We generally ask here on SO that you at least spend some time trying to convert it yourself by reading documentation and other SO answers, rather than justs asking other people to do the work for you.

Comment: I'm bored, that's why I've answered this otherwise, I totally agree with @KatyaHandler

Comment: yep, i agree with you. solution is here rows.mapValues(lambda x: (x, 1)).reduceByKey(lambda x, y: (x[0] + y[0], x[1] + y[1])).collect()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the few information you have given and the quality of the question, the following might be a solution :

```
rdd = sc.parallelize(((7, 6, "dev14", 2016, 22.0),(7, 6, "dev11", 2016, 21.0),(2, 6, "dev12", 2016, 62.0),(2, 6, "dev18", 2016, 28.0),(1, 6, "dev15", 2016, 22.0)))
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd, ['user', 'x','y','z','t'])
df2 = df.groupBy(df.user).agg({ "t" : "avg" }).show()
# +----+------+
# |user|avg(t)|
# +----+------+
# |   1|  22.0|
# |   2|  45.0|
# |   7|  21.5|
# +----+------+
```

We can check `df2` columns :

```
df2.columns
# ['user', 'avg(t)']

df2['avg(t)']
# Column<avg(t)> <-- that's a column

df2.select(df2['avg(t)']).show()
# +------+
# |avg(t)|
# +------+
# |  22.0|
# |  45.0|
# |  21.5|
# +------+
```

Comment: how can i call the avg(t) column ?

Comment: Maybe averageDF['avg(t)'].

Comment: ah no , said it's not callable dataframe

Comment: What are you talking about ? You have to call the data from which you used to save the result of my query. I'm on my phone right now. I can't edit that question.

Comment: ah i am afreaid but you are wrong . could you try averageDF= df.groupBy(df.user).agg({ "t" : "avg" })    ////   averageDF['avg(t)'] .

Comment: I'm afraid, I'm not. I have edited the answer. I really advise you to read some doc thought. This is Spark ABC !